# Saved audio received from WebRTC

Tags: c#, .net-core, webrtc

Based on [this guide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/helloworld-cs-mediatracks-core3.html), I set up a WebRTC communication, according to the [description](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/helloworld-cs-connection-core3.html), the audio frames are received as follows.

```
                pc.AudioTrackAdded += (RemoteAudioTrack track) =>
                {
                    var readerBuffer = track.CreateReadBuffer();
                    track.AudioFrameReady += (AudioFrame frame) =>
                    {

                        IntPtr a = frame.audioData;

                        // NEED TO SAVE AUDIO

                    };

                };
```

I'm looking for a way to save Audio stream or achieve an array of bytes stream

Comment: Are you looking for [AudioTrackReadBuffer.Read](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.AudioTrackReadBuffer.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_WebRTC_AudioTrackReadBuffer_Read_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Single___System_Int32__System_Boolean__Microsoft_MixedReality_WebRTC_AudioTrackReadBuffer_PadBehavior_)?

Comment: Can you prepare a sample? @Steeeve